# Why memoization works, but returns false value from unordered_map

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

The following program countConstruct should return the number of possible way the target string can be constructed from the given wordBank. Now, the memo object seem to store the correct value for "ab" which is 2, but it prints out 1. I just cannot figure out, what am I keep missing here over and over again. I appreciate anyone who can enlighten me about my failiure. Thank you.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

unordered_map<string, int> memo;

bool countConstruct(const string& target, const vector<string>& wordBank)
{
    if (target.size() == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (memo.find(target) != memo.end())
    {
        return memo[target];
    }

    int totalCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < wordBank.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (wordBank[i].size() <= target.size())
        {
            string prefix = target.substr(0, wordBank[i].size());
            if (prefix == wordBank[i])
            {
                totalCount = totalCount + countConstruct(target.substr(wordBank[i].size()), wordBank);
            }
        }
    }

    return memo[target] = totalCount;
}

int main()
{
    // int c = countConstruct("purple", vector<string>({"purp", "p", "ur", "le", "purpl"}));
    // int d = memo["purple"];
    // memo.clear();
    // cout << "countConstruct(purple, {purp, p, ur, le, purpl}) = " << countConstruct("purple", vector<string>({"purp", "p", "ur", "le", "purpl"})) << '\n';
    // memo.clear();
    // cout << "countConstruct(abcdef, {ab, abc, cd, def, abcd}) = " << countConstruct("abcdef", vector<string>({"ab", "abc", "cd", "def", "abcd"})) << '\n';
    // memo.clear();
    // cout << "countConstruct(skateboard, {bo, rd, ate, t, ska, sk, boar}) = " << countConstruct("skateboard", vector<string>({"bo", "rd", "ate", "t", "ska", "sk", "boar"})) << '\n';
    // memo.clear();
    // cout << "countConstruct(enterapotentpot, {a, p, ent, enter, ot, o, t}) = " << countConstruct("enterapotentpot", vector<string>({"a", "p", "ent", "enter", "ot", "o", "t"})) << '\n';
    // memo.clear();
    // cout << "countConstruct(eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeef, {e, ee, eee, eeee, eeeee, eeeeee}) = " << countConstruct("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeef", vector<string>({"e", "ee", "eee", "eeee", "eeeee", "eeeeee"})) << '\n';
    // memo.clear();

    cout << "countConstruct(ab, {ab, a, b}) = " << std::flush << countConstruct("ab", vector<string>({"ab", "a", "b"})) << "\n";
    cout.flush();
    memo.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `countConstruct` should return an `int` instead of `bool`?

Comment: ```return memo[target] = totalCount;``` does not look right

Comment: ***return memo[target] = totalCount;*** Did you want a comparison or an assignment??

Comment: Yes, that return type does look like one of the "forest-for-the-trees" issues you could stare out for quite sometime before snapping to it ... `:)` (we've all had those moments of brilliance in programming...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change bool --> int

Now it outputs:

```
countConstruct(ab, {ab, a, b}) = 2
```

Final code:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

unordered_map<string, int> memo;

int countConstruct(const string& target, const vector<string>& wordBank)
{
    if (target.size() == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (memo.find(target) != memo.end())
    {
        return memo[target];
    }

    int totalCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < wordBank.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (wordBank[i].size() <= target.size())
        {
            string prefix = target.substr(0, wordBank[i].size());
            if (prefix == wordBank[i])
            {
                totalCount = totalCount + countConstruct(target.substr(wordBank[i].size()), wordBank);
            }
        }
    }
    return memo[target] = totalCount;
}

int main()
{
    // int c = countConstruct("purple", vector<string>({"purp", "p", "ur", "le", "purpl"}));
    // int d = memo["purple"];
    // memo.clear();
    // cout << "countConstruct(purple, {purp, p, ur, le, purpl}) = " << countConstruct("purple", vector<string>({"purp", "p", "ur", "le", "purpl"})) << '\n';
    // memo.clear();
    // cout << "countConstruct(abcdef, {ab, abc, cd, def, abcd}) = " << countConstruct("abcdef", vector<string>({"ab", "abc", "cd", "def", "abcd"})) << '\n';
    // memo.clear();
    // cout << "countConstruct(skateboard, {bo, rd, ate, t, ska, sk, boar}) = " << countConstruct("skateboard", vector<string>({"bo", "rd", "ate", "t", "ska", "sk", "boar"})) << '\n';
    // memo.clear();
    // cout << "countConstruct(enterapotentpot, {a, p, ent, enter, ot, o, t}) = " << countConstruct("enterapotentpot", vector<string>({"a", "p", "ent", "enter", "ot", "o", "t"})) << '\n';
    // memo.clear();
    // cout << "countConstruct(eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeef, {e, ee, eee, eeee, eeeee, eeeeee}) = " << countConstruct("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeef", vector<string>({"e", "ee", "eee", "eeee", "eeeee", "eeeeee"})) << '\n';
    // memo.clear();

    cout << "countConstruct(ab, {ab, a, b}) = " << std::flush << countConstruct("ab", vector<string>({"ab", "a", "b"})) << "\n";
    cout.flush();
    memo.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return (memo[target] = totalCount);` is also another way to handle it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes let me edit it

Comment: You were correct -- that was just an alternative. To finish the cleanup, `for (size_t i = 0; i < wordBank.size(); ++i)` would avoid comparison between signed and unsigned values. (nit)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin General Question for one of my implementation that I am using several for loops: How much do you think is it faster to use size_t instead of int etc?

Comment: It's not that it's faster, it's that it is the proper **type** to match what is returned by `wordBank.size()`. Problems can arise because `wordBank.size()` can return a value greater than can be represented by `int`. (it won't in this case, but that is the reason you match the variable type to the return type when used in a loop test-condition) See [std::unordered_map::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/size)

Comment: Thank you guys, indeed I had a brilliant moment, starting out from a previous problem resulting whether is it possible to create target string or not, and I didn't modify the return value.